# How to get list of Facebook friends for testing an app, given the new Graph API limitations?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a JS Facebook app that searches the most recent status post from each of my friends, but I've run into a significant development obstacle:  As of v2.0 of the Graph API, `/me/friends` only lists friends who have installed the app.

Here's the code I was using:

```
function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');

    FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
        var statusElement=document.getElementById('output');
        statusElement.innerHTML=JSON.stringify(response.data);  
    });
  }
```

This returned no results, which I assume is because I am the only user who has installed this app. I understand that this is a good change for protecting users' privacy, and I'm not complaining about that.

Some other SO answers suggested using `taggable_friends` as a workaround, but that requires app review; how can I build and test the app to make it reviewable if I don't have a way to retrieve a sample data set of friends?  I could ask some of my friends to install it so that their statuses will be available, but I would rather wait to ask that favor until I'm sure that the app is working properly and won't cause them any problems.

So, how do developers who are starting work on a new app that uses `taggable_friends` do their initial work to prepare the app for review?  Or do I not need to have a working app to pass review?

Comment: Have you tried using test users?

Comment: There's a `user_friends` permission that you will have to request as part of the app's permissions, and the user *must* give it to you for that list to be generated. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/friends

Comment: @RyanWillis, I know that there's a `user_friends` permission, but I would really like to have something working before I ask a user to trust my app with their data.

Comment: @Igy, what do you mean by "test user"; does FB provide a way to create dummy friends for testing purposes?

Comment: @Igy, looks like you're talking about [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/test-user).  I'll check that out and see if it works.

Comment: No, that's still inviting actual users; I'll need something else.

Comment: Creat another fb app and sandbox your code with your own account(s)

Comment: @Alexandre, no, as far as I know, any meaningful content from my friends is only accessible if they give my app permission.

Comment: In the mid-time I found a way to test it, you must use the test-user, then you can login as them and make them being friends...

Comment: @Alexandre, that means I need to create a second account, right?  Is that allowed by the Facebook Terms of Service?

Comment: It's some test account available in the Facebook developer dashboard. Facebook create this account automatically for you and provide you a special link to connect with them. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users?locale=de_DE#managetool

Comment: @Alexandre, if you post this answer (similar to ceejayoz's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28051214/619177)) then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test this with test user from your dashboard.

"A test user is a special Facebook account, invisible to real accounts, which can be created within an app for the purpose of manual or automated testing of that app's Facebook integration."

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users

You must login as a test user and request a friendship with another of your test user. Add the app to the test user. Connect with the second test user. Accept the friendship and add the app as well. Then you can test your app with this same account and see the list of friends using your app