# Can I create a second Facebook account for testing without violating the TOS?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to develop a Facebook app that reads statuses posted by a user's friends.  However, it seems that I can only read friends' statuses if they've given the app a `user_friends` permission.  So, to test my app before I actually release it to my friends, it seems I'll need to set up a test account, set up a friend relationship between that account and my account, and then have the test account give the app permission.

Is making a second account for this purpose allowed under the TOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook has a tool (and API) for generating test users for your app, which you can find in your app's dashboard's "Roles" tab.

[image: Test Users]

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users#managetool

Comment: That's not for creating a test account.  That's for giving one of my actual friends test access to the app.  I just tried it and it requires that I provide the user name of one of my friends, I can't just enter "test abcdefg" as a username.  I want to make sure the app works before I ask one of my friends to test it.

Comment: Testers and Test Users are two different things. Testers are what you describe. There are also Test Users in a separate tab